# in app purchase sandbox expiryTimeMillis calculation

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

When purchasing an android in-app subscription of one month, google gives one day subscription in sandbox, but i'm not receiving correct time although date is correct, time is coming random.

This result should come:

**startTimeMillis: '1508757146149'(GMT: 23 October 2017 11:12:26.149)**

**expiryTimeMillis: '1508843546109'(GMT: 24 October 2017 11:12:26.109)**

But i'm getting this:

**startTimeMillis: '1508757146149'(GMT: 23 October 2017 11:12:26.149)**

**expiryTimeMillis: '1508830213348'(GMT: 24 October 2017 07:30:13.348)**

Why time part is not same?

Comment: did you tried subscribing at GMT: 23 October 2017 07:30:13.348 ?

Comment: i subscribed at GMT: 23 October 2017 11:12:26.149